# Date time is not changing in wpf when the zone changed

Tags: wpf, time, timezone

I having date Time, which comes from server. I need to change that time according to the machine zone. I am using following code to achieve that but time is not changing.

```
 DateTime utcTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(UserDateTime.ToString()), DateTimeKind.Utc);
 TimeZoneInfo localZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
 var time= TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime , localZone);
```

But when I selected another zone, the time is not changing according to the selected zone.

What I am looking forward for is, if I have DateTime like: 16-09-2020 07:21 as server time, When I change the zone in my machine to `London` the date has to display to the relevant time (16-09-2020 02:51).

Please guide me to achieve this.

Comment: What time zone is the server in? It's never 5 hours between UTC and UK time. You must know the time zone of the timestamp you get from the server to be able convert it.

Comment: You shouldn't ever create a string just to parse it again.  Your whole code can condense to `var time = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(UserDateTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local);`.  Is that what you want?  Also, what specifically do mean by "which comes from server"?  And what does this have to do with WPF?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [ConvertTime(DateTime, TimeZoneInfo, TimeZoneInfo)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077) method that converts a time from one time zone to another.

Obviously you need to know what time zone to convert from and which one to convert to.

If you are converting from UTC, there is a `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc` method as well. The following code snippet converts between UTC and UK time:

```
DateTime utcTime = new DateTime(2020, 9, 16, 07, 21, 00);
DateTime londonTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime,
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time"));
```